# Malfunctioning in Lollipop but Functioning in KitKat

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to give an EndGame response to players based on their performance on a game.

I access the method "onDraw" from MainActivity to display the message.

It works like a charm in Kitkat but on lollipop it somehow crashes.

Here are the codes:

In MainActivity

```
if (rec.getGameOver()) {
            saveScore(rec.getScore());
            rec.onDraw(rec.getCanvas());
        }
```

In Game class extends view

```
 if (score > value) {
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            paint.setTextSize((int) (value));
            canvas1.drawText("Nice!", 0, (int) (value), paint);
            canvas1.drawText("Your got" + score, 0, (int) (value), paint);
        } else {
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            paint.setTextSize((int) (value);
            canvas1.drawText("Try Again?!", 0, (int) (value), paint);
            canvas1.drawText("Your got" + score, 0, (int) (value), paint);
        }
        invalidate();
```

Every variable was already defined before use.

edit: here is the error

`06-20 16:14:51.656   1232-26777/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Exception thrown during pause
    android.os.DeadObjectException
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
            at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:704)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:825)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2726)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2583)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2497)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11500)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11397)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:12081)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:11592)
            at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)`

Comment: You are using onDraw wrong, never call it yourself. Call invalidate.

Comment: edit. nvm I saw your answer. Thanks so much! It's fixed.